# MYSQL join two tables, with matching value from second table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have two tables [tags] and [tags_to_item]

```
tag_id name          tag_id  item_id
------ -------       ------  -------
1      Pirate         1       3
2      Monkey         2       9
3      Ninja          3       12
4      Spaghetti      4       3
```

the first one is a table of tags, the second stores the relations between tag and item

eg.

> item 12 is associated with tag 'Ninja'     item 3 is associated with
>   tag 'Pirate' and 'Spaghetti'

given these tables
i want to join them so I can show all the tags available, BUT showing which of those tags have been associated with a given item id

> ok say  I want to check item_id = 3

Desired output:

```
tag_id   name       item_id
------   -------    -------
1        Pirate     3
2        Monkey     null
3        Ninja      null
4        Spaghetti  3
```

i tried this query but it doesn't work as expected...it doesn't show the full list

```
SELECT a.name, a.tags_id, o.item_id from tags as a
left outer join tags_to_item as o on a.tags_id = o.tags_id WHERE o.item_id = 3
union all
select a.name, a.tags_id, o.item_id from tags as a
right outer join tags_to_item as o on a.tags_id = o.tags_id
```

---

**UPDATE**:

thank to @Gordon I' getting closer to what I need, this is a decent query

```
SELECT a.tags_name, a.tags_id, o.item_id from tags as a
left   join tags_to_item as o on a.tags_id = o.tags_id AND o.item_id = 3
union     
select a.tags_name, a.tags_id, o.item_id from tags as a
right   join tags_to_item as o on a.tags_id = o.tags_id AND o.item_id = 3 where a.tags_id != null
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
select t.tags_name, t.tags_id, tti.item_id
from tags t left join
     tags_to_item tti
     on a.tags_id = o.tags_id and tti.item_id = 3;
```

Note that the condition on the item has been moved from the `where` clause to the `on` clause.  If you do the comparison in the `where` clause, you turn the outer join into an inner join.

Also, I put in more reasonable table aliases.  Don't use arbitrary letters like `a` for table aliases.  Use table abbreviations.

Comment: your code doesn't not work but your suggestion does (almost)! adding AND in the ON statement instead of WHERE does produce my need, but for some reason i also get extra row i dont want. i'll update my post

Comment: @Francesco . . . You would get an extra row if you had duplicates in `tags_to_item`.

Answer (score 0):

Used below query this is working.

```
select t.tag_id,t.name , 
(case when (select tag_id from tags where tag_id=tti.item_id) 
 THEN
      tti.item_id
 ELSE
      NULL 
 END) as item_id
from tags as t
left join tag_to_item as tti ON tti.tag_id = t.tag_id;
```

Used mysql case operator. under the case operator execute the another sql query. where checked tags table having current item_id or not.if tags table having item_id then show the item_id other wise show the null string.